# ¿Por qué me pide la clausula into en el select?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedure

Tengo un caso con mi sentencia select en oracle ya que me pide la clausula into cuando quiero crearlo como procedimiento almacenado pero cuando lo ejecuto fuera no hay ningún problema, esta es la sentencia:

```
select sum(Cantidad) as Cantidad,Fecha_proceso,TO_CHAR(Fecha_proceso,'DD') as dia, Cod_Estacion 
from Comercial.VENTA_DETALLADA 
WHERE TO_CHAR(Fecha_proceso,'MM')= '02' AND TO_CHAR(Fecha_proceso,'YYYY')= '2018' 
group by Cod_Estacion, Fecha_proceso, TO_CHAR(Fecha_proceso,'DD') order by Fecha_proceso,COD_ESTACION ;
```

en este caso si ejecuta normal pero cuando lo pongo en un procedimiento así salta el error al momento de crearlo

```
create or replace PROCEDURE REPORTE_VENTAS_DETALLADAS(
mes VARCHAR2,
anio VARCHAR2
)
IS
BEGIN

select sum(Cantidad) as Cantidad,Fecha_proceso,TO_CHAR(Fecha_proceso,'DD') as dia, Cod_Estacion 
from Comercial.VENTA_DETALLADA 
WHERE TO_CHAR(Fecha_proceso,'MM')= '02' AND TO_CHAR(Fecha_proceso,'YYYY')= '2018' 
group by Cod_Estacion, Fecha_proceso, TO_CHAR(Fecha_proceso,'DD') order by Fecha_proceso,COD_ESTACION ;

END;
```

el error es :

```
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
```

Espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

En un query en el IDE los resultados van a la pantalla, en un procedimiento almacenado generalmente esos resultados son variables en una clausula into y de ahi en adelante ya puedes usarlos, en base a esas variables, por eso te marca error. Te pregunta ¿a donde van a ir los resultados de tu query en store procedure? y como no le dices te marca error. La forma de decirle es la clausula into

Comment: Un método en c#  llama al procedimiento que contiene el query.
Lo que entiendo es que tengo que tener una variable (¿de algún tipo en especial?) para recibir la información del query para luego poder manipularla pero son varios registros de respuesta.

Comment: asi es, es una lista de variables,cada variable debe ser del tipo que devuelve el query en cada columna, o puede ser una única variable, y te almacenará todo

Comment: Si deseas regresar todo el conjunto de datos (registros y columnas) esos son de tipo cursor en oracle

Comment: Recuerda votar por la respuesta que mas te ayudo.